# How to "fix" debugger in VScode if you have Makefile project on C++?

Tags: c++, makefile, vscode-debugger

I have problem ,I have Make project(multiple c++ files ) written on C++ . I am trying using VScode debugger to debug it but it just freezes and dats all, How to fix debugger what parameters in VSCodes json I must change e.t.c?
Projects folder config:

Makefile

```
exe
```

src (folder where all o and cpp h files are/will be stored)
       IN SRC FOLDER :
    main.cpp
    WGForeCast.h
    WGForeCast.cpp 
    etc

my task.json

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make",
        "args":["${workspaceFolder}/Makefile"]
    }
]
}
```

my launch

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Pusk",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well I found the solution :
First
In Makefile you need add option -g flag to compiler to use, “ ***-g*** ”: Generates debugging information that is used by gdb-baseddebuggers
Adding a flag example

```
CC=g++ -g -Wall
```

Just in case rebuild your project with the added flag before continue;

Second you need to change ***task.json*** in your project
To create a launch.json file, open your project folder in VS Code (***File > Open Folder***) and then select the Configure gear icon on the Debug view top bar. Chose ***gdb***(for LInux) then ***launch.json*** will be generated but you need to change it like so:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "name": "Pusk", //I named it Pusk because i can 
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Pusk", //path to your programs exe and exe name
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Third we must configure ***task.json***(basically its kinda script to launch your programm using Makefile instead the default compiler).
***To create task.json***

```sh
    1)Open a folder with vscode
    2)Hit F1
    3)Select "Tasks: Configure Task Runner"
    4)Hit Enter and vscode will create a sample task.json for you
```

Change **task.json** like so(probably do not need so complicated one but ¯(ツ)/¯ )

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make", //its like writing in console make //btw you can others commands like clean make build etc
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": {
          "owner": "cpp",
          "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
          "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Rebuild your project by pressing  ***Ctrl+Shift+B***(its like make in console now, because we changed task.json)
***DATS ALL!! YOU CAN NOW USE DEBUGER!!!***
Source->[see "debug in vs code" article](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/CS-Wiki/wiki/C-and-Cpp-Debugging-in-VS-Code)