# Debugging an existing project with Makefile in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, makefile

I am trying to debug a project I downloaded from Github. The compilation was without any errors through the command line and I executed the project in this way :
`./final -i name -n 2` in the terminal and everything was OK. I opened the folder containing my project and followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/9VpiGwp8Vos) to debug my project with Makefile. This is the content of my launch.json, but when I hit debug, I get the error that the file in the specified path is `invalid or missing`.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": " ${workspaceFolder}/final",
            "args": ["-i name", "-n 2"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The content of Makefile is just too large to post it here, so I just post the first lines indicating that `-g` is there.
The first lines of Makefile:

```
.SILENT:
.SUFFIXES: .cxx
.PHONY: library
CXXOBJECTS=final.o 
LIBOBJECTS= bunch of .o 
OBJECTS=$(CXXOBJECTS) $(LIBOBJECTS)
DEBUG=-g
OPT=-O3 -DNDEBUG -g
OPT_DEBUG=$(OPT) 
CXX_COMPILE=g++ -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -fPIC $(OPT_DEBUG)  -I/Path  -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial $(EXTRAFLAGS)
CXX_LINK=g++ -fPIC $(EXTRAFLAGS) $(OPT_DEBUG)
THISDIR=/path
```

Comment: Why do you think that running the debugger from Visual Code has anything to do with your makefile?  Makefiles are used to compile the project.  It seems that was done correctly and the resulting binary runs.  So I'd say the makefile is fine.  It would probably help if you were more specific about the error: you say _the file in the specified path is invalid or missing_; which file in which path?  What is the exact error message (cut and paste please)?

Comment: Unable to start debugging.Program path `/home/user-name/Project/final` is missing or invalid. GDB failed with message: /home/user-name/Project/final : no such file or directory . This may occur if the process's executable was changed after the process was started. such as when installing an update. Try relaunching the application or restarting the machine

Comment: It could not be copied, I typed it so

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779252/13519156) solved my problem.  The problem was that I also needed to modify tasks.json file