# debugging c code compiled with Makefile using vscode and lldb on linux

Tags: c, makefile, vscode-debugger, lldb

I am using vscode on archlinux and I need to debug line by line a C code compiled  with a makefile.
I have create a task and a launch json which me allow to examine step by step, but I cannot inspect variable throw debug console or through vscode interface.

This is an extract of Makefile

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-unreachable -Wswitch-bool \
          -Wmisleading-indentation -Wnull-dereference -Winit-self -Wstack-protector -Wformat \
          -Wformat-security -Wformat-overflow -Wdouble-promotion -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-const-variable \
          -Wuninitialized -Wpointer-arith -Wincompatible-pointer-types -Wbad-function-cast \
          -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wlong-long -Og -g -O0\
          -Ofast
LDFLAGS = -gdwarf-2 -L/usr/local/lib


.PHONY: clean cleandep mrproper

all: $(EXEC)

myprogram: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -g  -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) 

[...]

debug: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: $(EXEC)
```

Regarding the launch and tasks json, they are the same i used in another file (compiled without makefile), so I am quite sure of them.

Basically, when I use the debug console "print <variable>", <variable> is not defined.
I copied this structure [How to "fix" debugger in VScode if you have Makefile project on C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581500/how-to-fix-debugger-in-vscode-if-you-have-makefile-project-on-c) but it used cppdb, which is not supported in archlinux.

UPDATE
my mistake, in main variable are printed, inside function called by the main, I cannot see variable content (undeclared identifier)

Comment: When you have multiple `-Ofoo` options like `-Og -O0 -Ofast` only the last one counts, btw. Stick with `-O` for serious debugging; even `-Og` optimizes too much stuff out IME.

Comment: what is "cppdb"? there is "cppdbg". no "cppdb".

Comment: @Shawn, thanks for the info, but I still have the problem, I keep all the Makefile as shown except for substituting "-Og -g -O0 -Ofast" flags with "-O" and I still have the problem I cannot see variable values.

Comment: @starball, yes, my mistake, is cppdbg, but in any case, it is not defined in archlinux distribution

Comment: *in main variable are printed, inside function called by the main, I cannot see variable content* Are you by chance trying to look at variables defined in `main` while in the child function?

Comment: Using `-O` is wrong.  That enables "basic optimization"; typically it's the same as `-O1`.  If you want to disable optimization then either don't add any `-O` option, or specify `-O0`.  See the manual for your compiler (GCC or Clang or whatever).

Comment: @Shawn, no sorry for my bad explanation, what i was saying is that from debug console
- print <variable in main> while the program is running in main -> print variable
- print <variable in function> while i step into function (current position, inside function) --> variable undefined

Comment: "variable undefined" almost always means that the variable was optimized out (or the optimizer messed up the debug info some other way - optimizers are often not kind to debug info.)  You really do want to make sure you have optimization turned off - usually "-O0" as others have said, or you will run into this sort of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is related to your problem, but this makefile is not very well formed.  Using target-specific variables like this is not a good idea.

We will assume (although you didn't provide enough of the makefile to be sure) that the `EXEC` variable is indeed set to the value `myprogram`.  Then you have this:

```
all: myprogram

myprogram: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -g  -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) 

debug: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: myprogram
```

The problem with this is that if you run `make` followed by `make debug` you might *think* you are building your program with the extra `-DDEBUG -g`, but you are not.

When you run `make` it builds all the object files and executable without the extra `-DDEBUG -g`.  Then when you run `make debug` it will see that all the targets are up to date already, and it *won't rebuild them*.  That means none of your extra flags have any effect.

If you change some source files and run `make debug`, then *only those source files* that you changed will be recompiled with the extra flags and only those source files will be compiled with debugging.

Make has no idea what options are being used and it can't tell whether they have changed.  It only knows about the modification times of files.

If you want to use this method of creating debug builds in your makefile, you **must** remember to do a `make clean` or equivalent (delete all the build products) every time you switch between running `make` (without debug) and `make debug`.  Otherwise you'll get a mish-mash of object files built different ways.

A more reliable, and more common, way to handle this is to write the output files for different types of builds to different directories: so the optimized object files and `myprogram` binary might go into an `opt` subdirectory and the debug object files and `myprogram` binary might go into a `debug` subdirectory.  Then make will understand which files were built with which flags, and they won't get confused.

Maybe you are already careful to do this clean operation and you just didn't mention it in your question.  There is simply not enough detail in your question to know what the problem is.  If you really want to know if the compilation is correct the best thing to do is *look at the compile lines* that make prints out when you run it.  Do you see the `-DDEBUG -g` options in those compile lines?  Do you see either no `-O` option, or else `-O0` as the last one?  It could be something completely different; for example maybe the rules you are using to compile the code (that you elided with `[...]`) are not right and are not being used.

Also just as a note, it's usually safest to put the `$(CFLAGS)` variable on the link line as well as the compile line; the compiler front-end will ignore compile options when it invokes the linker but the linker wants to know about, for example, the `-g` option to enable debugging.

Comment: I'd keep all the warning options from the original.

Comment: If anything about my answer could be read as suggesting removing the warnings options, I didn't intend for it to do so...

Comment: You left them out like they were something not not important/necessary.

Comment: I don't think I did.  I didn't intend to quote the entire makefile from the question, only the important parts for understanding the behavior of the target-specific variable setting.  And in the text I always said "the _extra_ flags".  But if anyone was confused, you should preserve the global setting of `CFLAGS`.

Comment: @MadScientist many thanks, as you said, in my case the problem clean was in make clean debug.